# How to control the direction of a hook arrow in diagxy?

Tags: xy-pic, commutative-diagrams

I'm converting some diagrams from `tikz-cd` to `diagxy` and am having problems with hook arrow for inclusion maps.

With `tikz-cd` the hook gets reversed on a right-to-left arrow, but I can restore it by adding an apostrophe.

With `xy` that's not an option, and changing the left parenthesis from a subscript to a superscript doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[barr,pdf]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
With tikzcd

\[\begin{tikzcd}
  A
    \ar[r, hook, "right~hook"']
& B \\
  A
& B
    \ar[l, hook', swap, "left~hook"']
\end{tikzcd}\]

With xy

\[
\bfig
\node a1(0,800)[A]
\node b1(1000,800)[B]
\node a2(0,700)[A]
\node b2(1000,700)[B]
\node a3(0,600)[A]
\node b3(1000,600)[B]
\node a4(0,500)[A]
\node b4(1000,500)[B]
\node a5(0,400)[A]
\node b5(1000,400)[B]
\node a6(0,300)[A]
\node b6(1000,300)[B]
\node a7(0,200)[A]
\node b7(1000,200)[B]
\node a8(0,100)[A]
\node b8(1000,100)[B]
\arrow |b|/_{ (}->/[a1`b1;right~sub~(]
\arrow |b|/^{ (}->/[a3`b3;right~sup~(]
\arrow |b|/_{ (}->/[b5`a5;left~sub~(]
\arrow |b|/^{ (}->/[b7`a7;left~sup~(]
\efig
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've finally found the bug, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line after `\usepackage[barr,pdf]{xy}`.

```
\newdir_{ (}{{ }*!/-.5em/@_{(}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[barr,pdf]{xy}
\newdir_{ (}{{ }*!/-.5em/@_{(}}
\begin{document}
Without space:
\[
\bfig
\node a1(0,800)[A]
\node b1(1000,800)[B]
\node a2(0,700)[A]
\node b2(1000,700)[B]
\node a3(0,600)[A]
\node b3(1000,600)[B]
\node a4(0,500)[A]
\node b4(1000,500)[B]
\node a5(0,400)[A]
\node b5(1000,400)[B]
\node a6(0,300)[A]
\node b6(1000,300)[B]
\node a7(0,200)[A]
\node b7(1000,200)[B]
\node a8(0,100)[A]
\node b8(1000,100)[B]
\arrow |b|/_{(}->/[a1`b1;right~sub~(]
\arrow |b|/^{(}->/[a3`b3;right~sup~(]
\arrow |b|/_{(}->/[b5`a5;left~sub~(]
\arrow |b|/^{(}->/[b7`a7;left~sup~(]
\efig
\]

With extra space:
\[
\bfig
\node a1(0,800)[A]
\node b1(1000,800)[B]
\node a2(0,700)[A]
\node b2(1000,700)[B]
\node a3(0,600)[A]
\node b3(1000,600)[B]
\node a4(0,500)[A]
\node b4(1000,500)[B]
\node a5(0,400)[A]
\node b5(1000,400)[B]
\node a6(0,300)[A]
\node b6(1000,300)[B]
\node a7(0,200)[A]
\node b7(1000,200)[B]
\node a8(0,100)[A]
\node b8(1000,100)[B]
\arrow |b|/_{ (}->/[a1`b1;right~sub~(]
\arrow |b|/^{ (}->/[a3`b3;right~sup~(]
\arrow |b|/_{ (}->/[b5`a5;left~sub~(]
\arrow |b|/^{ (}->/[b7`a7;left~sup~(]
\efig
\]
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** I have contacted Michael Barr, the maintainer of `xybarr`. According to him it is not a bug, but a deliberate omission, and he is not planning to add it.

Comment: I need to add a space to avoid run-in. I'll try / _^(->/ and see what happens.